# CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_meta() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_meta() on null here

```
$Sperson = $item_val->get_meta( 'Sales Person', true );
```

This is preventing payments going through on the checkout page. An empty notification error is shown on the checkout page when a user clicks pay and complete order. When the below code is removed, payments go through.

The code prints the sales person to the order email

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item','rw4y_add_custom_order_line_item_meta',10,4);
function rw4y_add_custom_order_line_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order){
    if (array_key_exists('shop_manager_id', $values)) {
        $custom_details = $values['shop_manager_id'];
        $shop_obj = get_user_by('id', $values['shop_manager_id']);  
        $item->add_meta_data('SID',$values['shop_manager_id'] );
        $item->add_meta_data('Sales Person',"[".$values['shop_manager_id']."] - ".$shop_obj->display_name );
        $SIID = $values['shop_manager_id'];
        if($SIID!='' &&  (get_post_meta( $order->id, 'SID', true ))=='')
        {                        
            update_post_meta( $order->id,'SID', $SIID );    
            $Sperson = $item_val->get_meta( 'Sales Person', true );
            update_post_meta($order->id, 'Sales Person', $Sperson );
        }   
    }
}
```

From Woo commerce status

> 2022-08-19T11:21:13+00:00 CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_meta() on null in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/roofw4u/inc/woocommerce-hooks.php:682
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): rw4y_add_custom_order_line_item_meta()
> #1 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #2 /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()
> #3 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(491): do_action()
> #4 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(438): WC_Checkout->create_order_line_items()
> #5 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(381): WC_Checkout->set_data_from_cart()
> #6 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(1183): WC_Checkout->create_order()
> #7 /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php(461): WC_Checkout->process_checkout()
> #8 /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): WC_AJAX::checkout()
> in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/roofw4u/inc/woocommerce-hooks.php on line 682

Comment: `$item_val` is not defined anywhere. Did you mean to use `$item`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983 link to php reference post, more specifically, the answer explaining about this error